# Javascript focus on previous row's first input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form presented in a table and each row has two input fields and in the last row it has two buttons "add-more" and "submit"

```
<form>
        <table>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table class="table no-border no-margin manage_admin_child_table">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-left" style="width:40%;">
                    <div data-role="input-control" class="input-control text">
                      <input type="text" name="operator[0][mcc]"  id="operator_mcc_0" placeholder="MCC" tabindex="1">
                      <button tabindex="" class="btn-clear" type="button"></button>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-left" style="width:40%;">
                    <div data-role="input-control" class="input-control text">
                      <input type="text" name="operator[0][mnc]" placeholder="MNC" tabindex="2">
                      <button tabindex="" class="btn-clear" type="button"></button>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:2%;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <span class="wrapper"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table class="table no-border no-margin manage_admin_child_table">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-left" style="width:40%;">
                    <div data-role="input-control" class="input-control text">
                      <input type="text" name="operator[0][mcc]"  id="operator_mcc_0" placeholder="MCC" tabindex="3">
                      <button tabindex="" class="btn-clear" type="button"></button>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="text-left" style="width:40%;">
                    <div data-role="input-control" class="input-control text">
                      <input type="text" name="operator[0][mnc]" placeholder="MNC" tabindex="4">
                      <button tabindex="" class="btn-clear" type="button"></button>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:2%;">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="text-left" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                    <a href="#" tabindex="5" class="remove-operator-code text-bold"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <span class="wrapper"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
              <div class="widget_box_footer_section">
                <a href="#" class="button meduim submit_button place-le add_field_button" id="add-operator" tabindex="6"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add More</a>
                <button type="submit" class="button meduim submit_button place-right" id="operator_submit" tabindex="7">
                  <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
```

when i click on add-more it adds the new row(there can be many rows, i have not included that javascript here i have hard-coded the form with two input rows) with two fields and a cross icon to remove that field. 
and to remove that field i have a javascript function as

```
  $(document).on('click','a.remove-operator-code',function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
  });
```

It is successfully removing that row, but i dont know where the focus is going , i want to fix this focus issue that when we remove the particular row, focus must go to the previous row's first input field

Comment: You mean always remove last row and focus on that is previous row input.

Comment: no , any row can be removed except first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$(document).on('click','a.remove-operator-code',function() { 
  vat prevtr = $(this).closest('tr').prev();
  if(prevtr.length)
     prevtr.find('input:first').focus()

  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you..

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/ajnf988s/

```
   $(document).on('click','a.remove-operator-code',function() { 
 $(this).parents('tr').prev('tr').find('input[type=text]:first').focus();
 $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  });
```